# Pytube RegexMatchError

Tags: python-2.7, youtube, pytube

I am trying to write script in python where a user is prompted to enter a youtube link on the command line. This link should then be downloaded

```
from pytube import YouTube

downloadFile = raw_input("Enter your Youtube link: ")
YouTube(downloadFile).streams.first().download()
```

However when the link is entered on the command line I get the following:

```
File "dl.py", line 10, in <module>
    YouTube(downloadFile).streams.first().download()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pytube/__main__.py", line 69, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pytube/extract.py", line 43, in video_id
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pytube/helpers.py", line 39, in regex_search
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex pattern ((?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*) had zero matches
```

I am able to get get it working via python interpeter.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a bit of rooting around this seems to do the trick

```
import sys # import sys 
import pytube

link = raw_input('Please enter a url link\n')
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
stream = yt.streams.first()
finished = stream.download()
print 'Download is complete'

sys.exit()
```